# sentiment analysis using python pandas and scikit learn

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, sentiment-analysis

I have a dataset of product review.I want to count words in a way that instead of counting all the words I want to count some specific words like ('Amazing','Great','Love' etc) and put this counting in a column called 'word_count'.Now our goal is to create a column products[‘awesome’] where each row contains the number of times the word ‘awesome’ showed up in the review for the corresponding product.we will use the .apply() method to iterate the the logic above for each row of the ‘word_count’ column.

First,we have to use a Python function to define the logic above. we have to write a function called awesome_count which takes in the word counts and returns the number of times ‘awesome’ appears in the reviews.

Next, we have to use .apply() to iterate awesome_count for each row of ‘word_count’ and create a new column called ‘awesome’ with the resulting counts. Here is what that looks like:
**products['awesome'] = products['word_count'].apply(awesome_count)**

Can anyone please help me with the code need for the problem mentioned above.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify what the question is? What isn't working?

Comment: Is this your assignment that you have posted here? SO is not a place for asking others to do your project. If you need help, I highly suggest searching for similar issues on a search engine, put some time to understand the concept, try to implement, and if you get any issues in the code, post that piece of code, and I am sure you can get the appropriate help then. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Alright I lied; for standalone getting word frequency over a corpus we can combine pandas and numpy like so:

```
word_A = np.array(df.series.str.findall('word'))
getlength = np.vectorize(len)
getlength(word_A)
```

***Whats going on under the hood:***

**LINE1**

- `pd.series.str` to convert the series to string;
- `str.finall()` return all occurrences of the *"pattern"* matched to a list element (findall is a re function); since we're inputting a string, it's going to return the string over and over each time it's matched. The result will be X number of list elements, where X is the amount of documents you searched, and Y strings of your word in each element, where Y is a copy of the string for each time it matched in that document;

For example, if you have 3 documents, and each document has the following matches of 'word': 1, 2, 4, you're list will look like:

```
[['word'], ['word', 'word'], ['word', 'word', 'word', 'word']]
```

- `np.array()` converts the list to an array (*so we can vectorize it*);

  `array([list(['word']), list(['word', 'word']), list(['word', 'word', 'word', 'word'])], dtype=object)`

**LINE2**

- `np.vectorize()` makes the function we pass it a ***vectorized function*** (primes it for numpy broadcasting);

**LINE3**

- apply our ***vectorized*** function to the array;

When the vectorized function (In this case, len()) is called in line 3, it goes through each array element and applies that function. The result is an array that index matches the initial document series, but contains an integer count of the search term. For example:

```
array([ 1, 2, 4])
```

***Note:*** I'd still recommend going the `slightly` longer route - and at least preprocessing your data before you do frequency statistics.

Hope this helps!

### **update**

How many words are you wanting, and how big is your dataset?

If your computer can handle it, you can use Sklearn’s CountVectorizer to transform your corpus into a dense matrix of ‘document rows’ (documents x words) where each value is the frequency of the word in that document.

From there, you can query the documents relative to their category using document indexes and get aggregate counts for all of the words.

This approach is more computationally rigorous and will take longer computing, but if you are going to be drawing a lot of EDA from the frequency it’s a good idea to just get the data in a matrix/frame if you can store it.

If you’re only doing a couple of words and aren’t expecting to do much analysis, then we can use NumPy arrays to return the index position of a document each time the word is found, then sum all of the returns (ie word frequency across the documents you searched).

Ideally before you aggregate word frequency and whatnot we want to preprocess the data (I.e. remove non-word characters, make lowercase, tokenize, lemmatize, etc.) This way you have better accuracy collecting your ‘Features,’ ie the words. “This is amazing!”, “I’m so amazed”, and, “She amazes me.” All return a different ‘token’ or feature for ‘Amaze’ though they all use it similarly.

If we don’t need to preprocess and we aren’t making many observations or data manipulations then we can do a quick array to capture words. You’ll still probably want to manually alter your words (Amazing -> amaz, etc), lowercase them, and tokenize your document strings.

An alternative approach would be to use regex and .apply() with a user function that appends the return of re.findall() to a list; but this is computationally inefficient so really only good for a handful of words across <500,000 documents; and even then depending on your processing power that’ll take minutes.

Or you might use listcomp to set the value directly to the cell location.

Sorry I’m not at computer; will check back later and add some code when I can. Let me know a little more about your dataset size please. Thanks!